# How to send JSON as a parameter in url using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to achieve same thing as this: [How to use query parameter represented as JSON with Spring RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423202/how-to-use-query-parameter-represented-as-json-with-spring-resttemplate), sending JSON string as a URL parameter in `restTemplate.exchange()`.

The accepted answer mentions that sending JSON object as request parameter is generally not a good idea since you will probably face problem with curly brackets inside JSON. That is exactly what is happening when I am trying to make a GET call to an API. Since this is an API from another system, I cannot ask them to change the format and will have to call the GET endpoint, passing JSON as parameter. How can I achieve this in `restTemplate.exchange()` call?

Note: The mentioned related question does not guide on how to overcome this problem and I do not have enough reputation to comment on it to ask the author of the answer.

Comment: And what's the problem with the response to the linked question? What is your code? What exact and complete error do you have?

Comment: The error I get is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"size"'`. The json looks like this: `{"size":10000,"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"term":{"run_id":"a5fc0cdb-0bce-4071-a850-77d181c0811d"}}}}}`

Comment: The linked question only shows how to get JSON from an object, not how to use it in `exchange()` to avoid the error I mentioned above.

Comment: If you want help with your code, post your code. And yes, it does show how to build a URL with parameter values.

Comment: @JBNizet: I see.. I got it working by sending URI instead of String. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question. While it is a bad idea to pass JSON like this in a query/url parameter, there is a workaround as suggested here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9220?focusedCommentId=76760&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-76760. 
 
Replicating the code here in case this link goes dead:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=*&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=venue_location&pt=28.0674,-80.5595&d=25";
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).build().encode().toUri();

System.out.println(uri);
// http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=*&q=*:*&fq=%7B!geofilt%7D&sfield=venue_location&pt=28.0674,-80.5595&d=25
```

Basically, instead of passing url having JSON query/url parameters as a string, pass it as a URI. Then call `exchange` method as before, but with URI instead of String:

```
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, passing an URI works like a charm!
In my case, I need to pass some params:
`UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);

URI uri = builder.build().expand(params).encode().toUri();
restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);`

Answer (score 1):

If this is 3rd party API and you cannot control or change JSON processing on backend side - there is no solution. Even if you will encode with URLEncoder - there is no guarantee that API backend would process such request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URLEncoder` class to encode the URL in `exchange` method, e.g.:

```
String url = "http://www.yoursite.com/api?param={\"some_key\":\"some_value\"}";
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
```

This will encode the characters (like braces and double quotes) and server then will decode it back to `json`.

Comment: I tried this. But `exchange` method ends up adding another encoding on top of this encoding, basically replacing all the `%` by `%25`. Hence, what server gets after decoding is another encoded string.

Comment: What if you send the request without encoding? Do you get 4xx or 5xx in return?

Comment: The error I get is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"size"'`. The json looks like this: `{"size":10000,"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"term":{"run_id":"a5fc0cdb-0bce-4071-a850-77d181c0811d"}}}}}`

Comment: So, I assume it is coming back from server (possibly 500 error)? If yes, could you post the code for `exchange` method?

Comment: @ Darshan Mehta: No, the exception is thrown while building the URL, even before making the network call. I will add my code shortly.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to query elasticsearch, why not use Search API then ;)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html